# How to add PlaceSelectionListener inside Nested Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-places-api

I'm developing google places API (https://developers.google.com/places/)in my application

My Requirement is : From `Activity` I have started `fragment1`,From `Fragment1` ,I'm starting `Fragment2` ,In `fragment2` i 've to call `SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment`,

**Issue** : I have done coding for this,If i try to entry any letter in Search Box,that will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for opening another fragment from current fragment right?

you can use this

Add following code in your **click listener** function,

```
 NextFragment nextFrag= new NextFragment();
 this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
 .replace(R.id.Layout_container, nextFrag,TAG_FRAGMENT)
 .addToBackStack(null)
 .commit();
```